# Australian English: neighbor or neighbour?

Tags: australian-english, endings

Several sites (say, https://www.grammar.com/neighbor_vs._neighbour, https://proofreadmydocument.com.au/writing-tips/differences-between-american-and-australian-english, https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090413020224AA64USB) say that Australian English favours neighbour over neighbor.

Why is it that a major search engine, on the contrary, favours

> site:.au "neighbor"

over

> site:.au "neighbour"

?

Comment: Interestingly, I see your *singular* searches return about twice as many hits for the AmE spelling as the BrE version, but when I search for the *plural* versions, the counts are about ***equal***. Which I suspect may simply reflect the orthography of the popular TV soap opera series [***Neighbours***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbours)

Answer (score 3):

I would not rely on Google hits for something like this. Any copyeditor will refer to an officially accepted dictionary, not Google. (Unless there is a specific house style guide that says something different.)

From the [Macquarie dictionary](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/features/word/search/neighbour/), both spellings are officially recognized, although *neighbour* is the preferred spelling. (This is similar to Canada, which uses the *Canadian Oxford Dictionary* and accepts both spellings but favours the UK spelling.)